# I faced this error when I try to run react-native expo cli

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

I installed expo cli using

> npm install -g expo-cli

then I created project named AwesomeProject as mentioned in docs and moved to that folder

> expo init AwesomeProject
> cd AwesomeProject

But when I try to run it using npm start or expo start, I am getting this error and I don't see any output

> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\Home\Documents\react-native\AwesomeProject\package.json npm
> ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory,
> open
> 'C:\Users\Home\Documents\react-native\AwesomeProject\package.json'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-08T07_02_20_464Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\Home\Documents\react-native\AwesomeProject\package.json npm
> ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: **no such file or directory**,
> open
> 'C:\Users\Home\Documents\react-native\AwesomeProject\package.json' npm
> ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm
> ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-08T07_02_20_464Z-debug.log

Check the bold line. It tells you that you are not in the directory which contains the `package.json` file.

It is because you have done

```
npm install & npm start
```

from not inside the project directory, to solve this issue. first do:

```
cd AwesomeProject
```

then:

```
npm install

npm start
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`expo init AwesomeProject cd AwesomeProject`

to

`expo init AwesomeProject AwesomeProject`

Then:

`cd AwesomeProject`

and:

`expo start`

You are giving two names to your project.